# Ros Arduino link problem

Tags: ros, rosserial, arduino#ros#raspberry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using this basic script on Arduino Uno to subscribe to "cmd_vel" topic and publish "cell_voltage" topic.

`include 'ros.h'
include 'std_msgs/Float32.h'
include 'geometry_msgs/Twist.h'
float x;
int sensorPin = A1;
int sensorValue = 0;
float voltageValue = 0;
ros::NodeHandle nh;
void messageCb( const geometry_msgs::Twist& vel)
{

x = vel.linear.x - 1.0;

}
std_msgs::Float32 float_msg;
ros::Publisher pu("cell_voltage", &float_msg);
ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> su("cmd_vel" , messageCb);
void setup() {

nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);


nh.initNode();


nh.subscribe(su);


Serial.begin(115200);

}
void loop() {

nh.spinOnce();


delay(10);


sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);


voltageValue = sensorValue * 5.0 /1023.0;


float_msg.data = voltageValue;


pu.publish(  &float_msg ); // THIS LINE

}`

When the line  `pu.publish(  &float_msg );`  is commented, everything works fine :

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=115200

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1491989648.891986] ROS Serial Python Node

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1491989648.915430] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1491989652.493960] Note: subscribe buffer size is 280 bytes

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1491989652.516291] Setup subscriber on cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]

But if I uncommented that line, I get this error message :

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=115200

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1491989671.577193] ROS Serial Python Node

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1491989671.604281] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1491989688.725894] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

However I am using the correct version. So I don't know why I have this message.

Any ideas ?

PS : What are the HTML tags for inserting cpp code ?

Regards

Matthieu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259076/ros-arduino-link-problem/) by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-12**:
The `preformatted text` button in the question editor will do block formatting for code, or you can indent each line by four spaces. ROS Answers uses a variant of markdown for post formatting, and while it also allows inline HTML, sometimes it's a bit too aggressive at trying to auto-close tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you forgot to advertise the topic after initlizing the node:

```
nh.initNode();
nh.advertise(pu);
```

Check tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

Tip: Before trying to connect using rosserial, check if the Arduino is still running: blinking leds or something.

For formating: There's a button with zeros/ones in the top.

---

Originally posted by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) with karma: 124 on 2017-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1